# How can I open two consoles from a single script

Tags: python, python-2.7

Apart from the scripts own console *(which does nothing)* I want to open two consoles and print the variables `con1` and `con2` in different consoles, How can I achieve this.

```
con1 = 'This is Console1'
con2 = 'This is Console2'
```

I've no idea how to achieve this and spent several hours trying to do so with modules such as `subprocess` but with no luck. I'm on windows by the way.

---

## Edit:

Would the `threading` module do the job? or is `multiprocessing` needed?

Eg:

[image]

Comment: there is only one console

Comment: Redirect your output to logfiles if necessary

Comment: So this isn't possible?

Comment: it is really possible

Comment: You can have one script that starts itself as a new subprocess, or you could get a native lib. But you definitely can do it.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621991/open-second-python-console (possible duplicate)

Comment: @ChrisLaplante I don't quite agree...

Comment: @KDawG: What additional requirements do you have?

Comment: You’re going to have to open the appropriate terminal one way or another, so yes – which OS?

Comment: What are the consoles you're talking about? Python interpreters?

Comment: @ChrisLaplante I don't see a proper solution also I've stated above What I've tried and my subsequent failure plus I have no intentions of sharing data between the two windows!

Comment: related: [Opening a Python thread in a new console window](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11712629/4279)

Comment: I don't understand your edit. I don't see any reason subprocess doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: @bukzor your always welcome to prove I'm wrong.

Comment: On Windows you can't have more then one console attached to process according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx So your only option is to use subprocess/multiprocessing. Using threading won't help you at all here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't want to [reconsider your problem and use a GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11713013/4279) such as in [@Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19796085/4279) then you could use `subprocess` module to start two new consoles concurrently and display two given strings in the opened windows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

messages = 'This is Console1', 'This is Console2'

# open new consoles
processes = [Popen([sys.executable, "-c", """import sys
for line in sys.stdin: # poor man's `cat`
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
"""],
    stdin=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True,
    # assume the parent script is started from a console itself e.g.,
    # this code is _not_ run as a *.pyw file
    creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
             for _ in range(len(messages))]

# display messages
for proc, msg in zip(processes, messages):
    proc.stdin.write(msg + "\n")
    proc.stdin.flush()

time.sleep(10) # keep the windows open for a while

# close windows
for proc in processes:
    proc.communicate("bye\n")
```

Here's a simplified version that doesn't rely on `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Show messages in two new console windows simultaneously."""
import sys
import platform
from subprocess import Popen

messages = 'This is Console1', 'This is Console2'

# define a command that starts new terminal
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    new_window_command = "cmd.exe /c start".split()
else:  #XXX this can be made more portable
    new_window_command = "x-terminal-emulator -e".split()

# open new consoles, display messages
echo = [sys.executable, "-c",
        "import sys; print(sys.argv[1]); input('Press Enter..')"]
processes = [Popen(new_window_command + echo + [msg])  for msg in messages]

# wait for the windows to be closed
for proc in processes:
    proc.wait()
```

Comment: why doesn't it display any text?

Comment: @KDawG: I've tested it on Python 3.3 windows 8. It works as written: two consoles pop up with the messages and they are closed in 10 seconds. The code should work without changes on Python 2.7

Comment: Windows 7 user here. When I run this, two console windows flash on screen and quickly close. Ten seconds later, I get `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`. (see full stack trace [here](http://pastebin.com/uqAdhwK6))

Comment: @Kevin: How do you run the script? Could you try: 1. Open a console in a directory with the script 2. Run `py the_script.py`

Comment: Yes, the result is the same.

Comment: @Kevin: could you remove `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag, to see actual errors produced by the children?

Comment: Ok. No errors here; just got [this](http://pastebin.com/grk7Yfep) output as expected. Maybe my antivirus is over-zealously blocking process communication. Any other Windows 7 users want to test?

Comment: @Kevin: if all else fails; `Popen("cmd /c start cmd /c".split() + [sys.executable, 'cat.py'], stdin=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)` is the next thing to try. It uses `new_window_command` from [keep multiple cmd windows open from batch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12122535/4279) that reported to work by at least one another person other than me.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian if this works as expected it certainly deserves the bounty unfortunately it still doesn't work *(just opens 2 empty windows)*

Comment: @KDawG: I've added a simplified version that doesn't rely on CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE. To avoid copy-paste errors, you could download it from https://gist.github.com/zed/7389278

Comment: @eryksun: 1. I don't remember why there is the second `cmd.exe /c`. There might have been some bug with the `start` command (`/wait` or `/b` options might behave unexpectedly) or I just left it there to switch to 'cmd.exe /k` easily. I can't test it right now. If you say it works without it; I'll remove it. 2. OP screenshots shows that `python.exe` is used.

Answer (score 6):

You can get something *like* two consoles using two Tkinter Text widgets.

```
from Tkinter import *
import threading

class FakeConsole(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, root, *args, **kargs)

        #white text on black background,
        #for extra versimilitude
        self.text = Text(self, bg="black", fg="white")
        self.text.pack()

        #list of things not yet printed
        self.printQueue = []

        #one thread will be adding to the print queue, 
        #and another will be iterating through it.
        #better make sure one doesn't interfere with the other.
        self.printQueueLock = threading.Lock()

        self.after(5, self.on_idle)

    #check for new messages every five milliseconds
    def on_idle(self):
        with self.printQueueLock:
            for msg in self.printQueue:
                self.text.insert(END, msg)            
                self.text.see(END)
            self.printQueue = []
        self.after(5, self.on_idle)

    #print msg to the console
    def show(self, msg, sep="\n"):
        with self.printQueueLock:
            self.printQueue.append(str(msg) + sep)

#warning! Calling this more than once per program is a bad idea.
#Tkinter throws a fit when two roots each have a mainloop in different threads.
def makeConsoles(amount):
    root = Tk()
    consoles = [FakeConsole(root) for n in range(amount)]
    for c in consoles:
        c.pack()
    threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop).start()
    return consoles

a,b = makeConsoles(2)

a.show("This is Console 1")
b.show("This is Console 2")

a.show("I've got a lovely bunch of cocounts")
a.show("Here they are standing in a row")

b.show("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
b.show("consectetur adipisicing elit")
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it suits you, but you can open two Python interpreters using Windows `start` command:

```
from subprocess import Popen
p1 = Popen('start c:\python27\python.exe', shell=True)
p2 = Popen('start c:\python27\python.exe', shell=True)
```

Of course there is problem that now Python runs in interactive mode which is not what u want (you can also pass file as parameter and that file will be executed).

On Linux I would try to make named pipe, pass the name of the file to python.exe and write python commands to that file. 'Maybe' it will work ;)

But I don't have an idea how to create named pipe on Windows. Windows API ... (fill urself).

Answer (score 1):

**`pymux`**

pymux gets close to what you want: https://github.com/jonathanslenders/pymux

Unfortunately it is mostly a CLI tool replacement for `tmux` and does not have a decent programmatic API yet.

But hacking it up to expose that API is likely the most robust option if you are serious about this.

The README says:

> Parts of pymux could become a library, so that any prompt_toolkit application can embed a vt100 terminal. (Imagine a terminal emulator embedded in pyvim.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows you can use win32console module to open a second console for your thread or subprocess output. This is the most simple and easiest way that works if you are on windows.

Here is a sample code:

```
import win32console
import multiprocessing

def subprocess(queue):
    win32console.FreeConsole() #Frees subprocess from using main console
    win32console.AllocConsole() #Creates new console and all input and output of subprocess goes to this new console
    while True:
        print(queue.get())
        #prints any output produced by main script passed to subprocess using queue

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
multiprocessing.Process(Target=subprocess, args=[queue]).start()
while True:
    print("Hello World")
    #and whatever else you want to do in ur main process
```

You can also do this with threading. You have to use [queue module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) if you want the queue functionality as threading module doesn't have queue

Here is the [win32console module documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32console.html)

Answer (score 0):

I used jfs' response. Here is my embellishment/theft of jfs response.
This is tailored to run on Win10 and also handles Unicode:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479504/how-can-i-open-two-consoles-from-a-single-script
import sys, time, os, locale
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

class console(Popen)  :
    NumConsoles = 0
    def __init__(self, color=None, title=None):
        console.NumConsoles += 1

        cmd = "import sys, os, locale"
        cmd += "\nos.system(\'color " + color + "\')" if color is not None else ""
        title = title if title is not None else "console #" + str(console.NumConsoles)
        cmd += "\nos.system(\"title " + title + "\")"
        # poor man's `cat`
        cmd += """
print(sys.stdout.encoding, locale.getpreferredencoding() )
endcoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(line.encode(endcoding))
    sys.stdout.flush()
"""

        cmd = sys.executable, "-c", cmd
        # print(cmd, end="", flush=True)
        super().__init__(cmd, stdin=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, encoding='utf-8')


    def write(self, msg):
        self.stdin.write(msg + "\n" )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myConsole = console(color="c0", title="test error console")
    myConsole.write("Thank you jfs. Cool explanation")
    NoTitle= console()
    NoTitle.write("default color and title! This answer uses Windows 10")
    NoTitle.write(u"♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥")
    NoTitle.write("♥")
    time.sleep(5)
    myConsole.terminate()
    NoTitle.write("some more text. Run this at the python console.")
    time.sleep(4)
    NoTitle.terminate()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you know about screen/tmux?

How about [tmuxp](http://tmuxp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? For example, you can try to run `cat` in split panes and use "sendkeys" to send output (but dig the docs, may be there is even easier ways to achieve this).

As a side bonus this will work in the text console or GUI.