# Python: Executing the windows command in windows command prompt from python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, command-prompt

I have to execute python script in windows command prompt

I am using the following command to run the command, so that the script opens the command prompt execute it

```
os.system("start /wait cmd /c {c:\\python27\\python.exe C:\\examples\\xml2html.py --dir c:\\Temp\\abcd c:\\tmp\\results.xml}")
```

I will be expecting a new directory called "abcd" created at that location and some output files created inside that.

When I run this command normally in the windows command prompt it works. I am not able to execute this in the script. Windows command prompt opens and terminates quickly.

Could any one let me know where exactly is it going wrong with the command please?

Comment: Should be fine. Did you check to see if the `abcd` directory was created?

Comment: What are curly braces for ? Just tried in windows prompt `cmd.exe /c echo foo` correctly outputs `foo`. But `cmd.exe /c { echo foo }` gives an error (in a Vista box).

Comment: @sshashank124 I have checked for that directory, it didn't create one

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am giving the complete command in that curly braces http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615455/python-start-new-command-prompt-on-windows-and-wait-for-it-finish-exit

Comment: @srp ; I'm afraid the curly braces in ref'ed post were just a typografic décoration. You should try to remove them. By the way do you really need so many interpretors ? Could'ny you just import second script and directly call a python function ?

Comment: unless `xml2html.py` doesn't allow it or you have a particular reason; import xml2html and use its functions directly instead of running it as a script.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I tried removing the curly braces and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to open a *new* console window you don't need to run `cmd.exe` (`%COMSPEC%`) in order to run another Python script as a subprocess:

```
import sys
from subprocess import check_call

check_call([sys.executable, "C:\\examples\\xml2html.py",
            "--dir", "c:\\Temp\\abcd", "c:\\tmp\\results.xml"])
```

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. I don't need to open a new console window. It worked.

Comment: @eryksun: you *can* use `cmd` to open a new console window e.g., see [this answer that opens two new console windows, namely `new_window_command`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19797600/4279) (`start` is a *shell* command)

Comment: @eryksun: you are right: it was ambiguous. I've updated the answer. The meaning is: you don't need a shell to run a Python script as a subprocess.