# Open 2 terminals and print 2 different message in Python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, terminal

I am new python (ver 2.7) programmer and I have a question how to open 2 terminals and output 
different message.

The main task of this program is open 2 terminals and output different message.
Right now, I have 3 following files

1. test.py -- it is the main file that suppose to open 2 terminals and call different python 2 files
2. print1.py -- this is simple 1 line of code which print the line of "this is 1st terminal"
3. print2.py -- same as print1.py. it output "this is 2nd terminal"

Currently, my test.py has following code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal','-x','python print1.py'])
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal','-x','python print2.py'])
```

When I execute the program, it opens two terminals and both of them tell "There was an error creating the child process for this terminal. Failed to execute child" .
Then, I have tried to write full path of print1/print2.py but it still gives same error and I am get stuck in there.
Please some give me some advice to solve this error.

Comment: related: [How can I open two consoles from a single script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19479504/4279). Have you tried the code from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19797600/4279)? How exactly does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `python` and the file path as separated items. Otherwise, `python print1.py` is interpreted as a program name instead of `python`.

```
import subprocess
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '-x', 'python', 'print1.py'])
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '-x', 'python', 'print2.py'])
proc1.wait()
proc2.wait()
```

NOTE: I changed `call` with `Popen`. `call` waits the program terminate; the second terminal will not be executed until the first program terminate.

**UPDATE**

BTW, unless the scripts does not pause after print, `gnome-terminal` will close as soon as the python program terminate.

If you want shell prompt after the program termination, put following lines at the end of each file (`print1.py`, `print2.py`):

```
import os
os.execv('/bin/sh', ['sh'])
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
From your advice, there is no error coming out now.
However, your os.execv seems not working...
Then, I have written this code in both print file for testing:


    print "this is first terminal"
    while 1:
    var = raw_input("Please enter something:)
    print var


When I execute the program, it first open terminal then it close the terminal immediately.

Could you give me some advice for this issue?

Comment: `os.execv('/bin/sh', ['sh'])` just works for me. Please run the `python print1.py` separately, then show me the error traceback if you have any.

Comment: python print1.py works perfectly. it print out message then it start shell. Thus I do not believe that print1.py has the problem. But when I try to execute from test.py, it launches new terminal then close it immediately.
I try to use both Popen and call but it seems it has same issue.

Comment: @Shin, What happen if you put `input()` at the end of the script?

Comment: It still has same issue.
From terminal, typing gnome-terminal -x python print1.py works perfectly fine.
But when i use subprocess.call / Popen, it has the issue

Comment: @Shin, I changed the code in the answer to wait sub-processes. Please try it as is, and let me know the result.

Comment: I have no idea why mine doesn't work.... I have pretty much same code as you have.

Comment: @Shin, Try this: `proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '-x', 'sleep', '10'])`. Does the terminally close immediately?

Comment: @Shin, Hmm.. it's strange.  Are you sure you specified `subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '-x', 'python', 'print1.py'])` ? (separated items)

Comment: yes, i specified it perfectly. 
Then I tried to change one of my print.py file to 


print 1111 
import time
time.wait(1000)

First it displays 1111 then wait until given time

Comment: @Shin, Seems like `os.execv` does not work for your system. Try replace it with `subprocess`: `import subprocess; subprocess.call(['/bin/sh'])`

Comment: Oh.... I finally got the right output!!
At the end of your print file, I put 
import time
time.sleep()
Then it works perfectly. It opens up terminal and stay the shell up. Thank you so much of your advice!

Comment: @Shin, I'm curious why `os.execv` does not work for you. `subprocess` module use `os.exec*` internally. Anyway, it's glad to help you. :)

Comment: No, os.execv works perfectly fine. what i need to do was add import time and time.sleep() at the end of you code.

Comment: @Shin, Do you mean, you appended `time.sleep(..)` after `os.execv(..)` call?

Comment: Yes, I have appended time.sleep() after os.execv() then it worked.

Comment: So time.sleep was the real key to stay terminal open in my enviroment.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTE 64-bit version and running on VirtualBox. if you are curious on my OS and environment, this is what I am using.

Comment: @Shin, I also using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit (in real machine).